# Spacing at last part of the regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I've the following regex:

`/(\(*)?(\d+)(\)*)?([+\-*\/^%]+)(\(*)?(\)*)?/g`

I have the following string:

`(5+4+8+5)+(5^2/(23%2))`

I use the regex to add space between numbers, arithmetic operators and parentheses.

I do that like:

`\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6`

That turns the string into:

`( 5  +   4  +   8  +   5 ) + (  5  ^   2  / (  23  %  2))`

As you can see the last two parentheses don't get spaced.

How can I make them space as well?

The output should look like:

`( 5  +   4  +   8  +   5 ) + (  5  ^   2  / (  23  %  2 ))`

Try out the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/NQvCxA/1/).

Comment: Try [`\b|(?<=\W)(?=\W)`](https://regex101.com/r/NQvCxA/2) and replace with space. This requires a method that performs multiple serarch and replace (like `preg_replace` in PHP).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are one of most gifted regex pattern writers that I have seen on SO.  Why don't you post your answers as answers like SO is designed?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments

Comment: @mickmackusa Because it is the same as Casimir's answer. We posted almost at the same time, so why duplicate?

Comment: @Wiktor So why comment if it provides duped info? I am asking you on a broader scale; you often drop patterns as comments.  I don't think you're scared to post them as answers because I know your patterns are always refined.  I'm wondering why you do it so often.

Comment: @mickmackusa I "drop patterns" to understand what the user really wants, as a means of clarification. For me, it is not a clear question, see, the comments under Casimir's answer prove I was right. Now, it is up to him to suffer from the OP question updates in the "do-that-and-this-for-me" style.

Comment: @mickmackusa  you should read carefully the comments... wiktor and casimir had posted at about the same time. So it wasn't a duped comment.

Comment: @Kixoka if it is duplicate information then the comment should be deleted to reduce page bloat.  If it is unique then it should be posted as an answer, not a comment.  Commenting solutions damages the intended page structure/design on SO.  I don't mean any disrespect.  I am asking for something quite simple for the benefit of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a simple and fast solution

**edit**
Some tips:
I know you are not validating the simple math expressions, but it would not hurt to do that before trying to beautify.

Either way you should *`remove all whitespace`* ahead of time
Find `\s+`  Replace `nothing`

To condense summation symbols you could do:
Find `(?:--)+|\++`  Replace `+`
Find `[+-]*-+*` Replace `-`

Division and power symbol meaning will vary with implementation,
and to condense them is not advisable, and better to just validate the form.

Validation is the more complex feat complicated by the meaning of parenthesis,
and their balance. That is another topic.

A minimum character validation should be done though.
String must be matched by `^[+\-*/^%()\d]+$` at least.

---

After optionally doing the above, run the beautifier on it.

https://regex101.com/r/NUj036/2

Find `((?:(?<=[+\-*/^%()])-)?\d+(?!\d)|[+\-*/^%()])(?!$))`
Replace `'$1 '`

Explained

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:                           # Allow negation if symbol is behind it
           (?<= [+\-*/^%()] )
           -
      )?
      \d+                           # Many digits
      (?! \d )                      #  - don't allow digits ahead
   |                              # or,
      [+\-*/^%()]                   # One of these operators
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?! $ )                       # Don't match if at end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this based on word boundaries and on non-word characters:

```
\b(?!^|$)|\W\K(?=\W)
```

and replace with a space.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hgd39L/3/)

details:

```
\b      # a word-boundary
(?!^|$) # not at the start or at the end of the string
|       # OR
\W      # a non-word character
\K      # remove characters on the left from the match result
(?=\W)  # followed by a non-word character
```

Comment: Is is possible to make it handle negative numbers as well?

Comment: @Drago: no, it's a different question.